# How to write results to multiple excel sheets in Python

Tags: python, xlwt

I am using `xlwt`to write to an excel file.However, I would like to split the results and write them into two different sheets (each sheet have 50% of the result):

```
result = [{},{}] #this is a result I am from the db
```

Comment: Could you please an example of the code that you are using to write the results?

Answer (score 0):

And where do you have a problem?
Just use xlwt quickstart:

```
data = [{'rows': [[1, 2, 3, 4]]}, {'rows': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]}]

import xlwt

for i, rows in enumerate(data):
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    ws = wb.add_sheet('A Test Sheet')


    for row_i, row in enumerate(rows['rows']):
        for row_j, value in enumerate(row):
            ws.write(row_i, row_j, value)

    wb.save('example{}.xls'.format(i))
```

Does it help?

Comment: using three for  it’s a low efficiency way

Comment: As far as I know xlwt do not support writing the row at once. But keep digging :) What efficiency do you need?

Comment: write the result into different sheet but in the same excel(XX.excel)!thanks

Comment: I know how to deel my problem,I got a grammar mistake,you share a good example! thanks!!

Comment: Great. Glad to hear :)